# Programmatically modifying a Sharepoint Online Excel file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-online

We need to create a c# application that can modify an Excel file in one of our Sharepoint online sites.

For a local file I do like this:

```
Excel.Application excel_app = new Excel.Application();
excel_app.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(
        <path to excel file>,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

But if I put the url of the Sharepoint Excel file it does not work. Is this feasible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the file, modify it, upload the file and replace it

Here is how to connect to a sharepoint site and upload a file

Use the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
...
using (var context = new SP.ClientContext(new Uri(<YOURSITEURL>))) {
    var web = context.Web;
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<NETWORK_USERNAME>, <NETWORK_PASS>, <DOMAIN_NAME>);
    context.Load(web);
    try
    {
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(new Uri(<FILE_URL>).AbsolutePath);
    context.Load(file);
    try
    {
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        file.SaveBinary(new SP.FileSaveBinaryInformation() { Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<NEW_FILE>) });
        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file(excel,word etc) to sharepoint online below is the code:
Note: create your project in .net FRAMEWORK(do not do this in .net core) and install the nuget package of Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

```
    ClientContext ccontext = new ClientContext("<URL>/sites/<foldername>");
    var securePassword = GetPasswordAsSecureString("<YOUR PASSWORD>"); // function is below
    ccontext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("<YOU-EMAIL-ID>", securePassword);
    ccontext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
    List lst = ccontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

 var DestSubFolder = "General/Data";
            Folder fileFolder = lst.RootFolder;
            if (DestSubFolder.Length > 0)
                fileFolder = CreateFolderInternal(ccontext.Web, lst.RootFolder, DestSubFolder);

    // upload File.
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    byte[] FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c://Temp/test.txt");
    newFile.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(FileContent);
    newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName("c://Temp/test.txt");
    newFile.Overwrite = true;

    fileFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    fileFolder.Update();
    ccontext.ExecuteQuery();

    private static SecureString GetPasswordAsSecureString(string password)
    {
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return securePassword;
    }
```